# Cannot call method - mocha

Tags: mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am running some test in my first smart contract called `Inbox.sol`.
I want to call the method `.message` in order to see if it is equal to the default variable I use when I deploy the contract with web3.

My **Inbox.sol** code

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.12;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    function initialInbox(string memory initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

My **test** file with Mocha is:

```
let accounts
let inbox

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  // Use one of those account to deploy the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: [INITIAL_ARGUMENT]})
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: GAS})
})

describe(('Inbox'), () => {
  it("has a default message", async () => {
    const message = await inbox.methods.message() // Returns a big object
    console.log(message)
    const messageCalled = await inbox.methods.message().call()
    console.log(messageCalled) // Returns nothing
    assert.strictEqual(message, INITIAL_ARGUMENT)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS `inbox` variable is an instance of `web3.eth.Contract` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html)).

The `inbox.methods.message()` is an instance of a helper object (that's the "Returns a big object" in your comment) containing the `.call()` method, that you need to use when you want to perform a read-only call.

```
const message = await inbox.methods.message().call() // Returns the string
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: Thanks. I wrote `const messageCalled = await inbox.methods.message().call()` but if I console.log it, I get nothing back

Comment: Nothing as an empty response? Or a `null`? Or the code never reached this point? ... If you got an empty response, that's correct, because the empty string is the default value for the Solidity `string public message;` property. You can change its value by executing either `initialInbox()` or `setMessage()` (by using `.send()`, not `.call()` because it's a read-write operation), but your test code never executes these funtions. So when you read the `message()`, it contains the default value (the empty string).

Comment: It reaches but it displays an empty response.
I think I do not have to set any message because I am deploying the contract as `   `.deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: [INITIAL_ARGUMENT]})`. So the initial value should be the one in `INITIAL_ARGUMENT`. No?

Comment: The `arguments` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy)) are passed to the `constructor`. But you have no `constructor` in the Solidity file, so the `arguments` field is effectively ignored... If you want to set the message during deployment, you need to create a constructor and set the message there.

Comment: I have the same case, and already I'm pass argument to construtor of .sol file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code and add a contractor.

```
function constructor(string memory initialMessage) public {
    message = initialMessage;
}
```

if you are using an older version of solidity for example ^0.4.17. you can create a constructor by create a method same name as your contract class.

```
function Inbox(string memory initialMessage) public {
    message = initialMessage;
}
```